# How to move the content of one tab to another based on some duration in laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.4

[image: Images on my tab menu]I have 4 tab menus. Initially,I have displayed the last inserted db record in one of the tabs.

But after some period of time duration,the content in that tab where checked and move to the next tab.

I will be using javascript,php and laravel framework.And I have no idea with this.

Please give me some references on this.

**Controller code:**

```
 public function show()
{

   $pendingFiles= priceInfo::all()->first();
    $count= count($pendingFiles);
    return view('MyList')->with('pendingFiles',$pendingFiles)-
  >with('count',$count);
}
```

this is my controller code.**.Here itself I had a doubt that,How to get the records based on updated time.**

**View code:**

```
 <div id="nonlive" class="tab-pane fade pull-center">
<br/>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs navbar-centre">
<li class="active pull-left" ><a data-toggle="tab" href="#qcverified">
<h4 ><strong>QCVerified</strong></h4></a></li>
<li class="pull-center"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#qcfailed"><h4>
<strong>QCFailed</strong></h4></a></li>
<li class="pull-center"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#qcpending"><h4>
<strong>QCPending  ({{$count}})</strong></h4></a></li>
<li class="pull-center"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#archieved"><h4>
  <strong>Archieved;</strong></h4></a></li>
 <br>
</ul>




<div class="tab-content">
<div id="qcverified" class="tab-pane fade in active">

</div>


<div id="qcfailed" class="tab-pane fade pull-center">

</div>
<div id="qcpending" class="tab-pane fade pull-center">

   <div class="row marketing">

  <div class="col-lg-15 tab-div" id="version_database" >
    <div  class='div-tab'>
     <div class="box">
      <div class="box-header">

        </div><!-- /.box-header -->
          <div class="box-body table-responsive">
            <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-
     hover dataTable" role="grid" aria-describedby="example2_info">
             <thead>
          <tr class="header">
              <th valign="middle" width="3%">S.no</th>
              <th valign="middle" width="10%">Product Details</th>
              <th valign="middle"  width="5%">SKUID</th>
                <th valign="middle" width="20%">Type of Request</th>
                <th valign="middle" width="5%">Action</th>

             </tr> 

            </thead>
            <tbody role="alert">
            <td>{{$pendingFiles->productId}}</td>
            <td>{{$pendingFiles->productName}}</td>
            <td>{{$pendingFiles->SKUID}}</td>
            <td>Create Request Listing</td>
            <td>action</td>


            </tbody>

                </table>
                </div>
                </div>

    </div>
  </div>
          </div>



</div>
<div id="archieved" class="tab-pane fade pull-center">

</div>

</div>


</div>
```

Comment: You're supposed to add some code of what you have tried and what failed in your approach. You can probably use some setTimeout and detach tho

Comment: Updated with my question

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

Firstly, you add url on each tab. like following.

```
Tab1: http://localhost/somepage/tab/1
Tab2: http://localhost/somepage/tab/2
Tab3: http://localhost/somepage/tab/3
```

And in javascript, you can trigger timer.

```
<script>
    var tab_id = '{{$tab_id}}';
    var time_in_ms = 10000;
    setTimeout(function(){
        location.href = '/somepage/tab/' + (tab_id + 1);
    }, time_in_ms);
</script>
```

Comment: will you please tell me what is the value of $tab_id

Comment: You can set it url GET parameter